# How do I pick up a weapon to open the door?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have completed the first playthrough of Borderlands 2 and have opted to do the second playthrough. The problem is that at a certain point where Claptrap gets his eye back, and you have to take a weapon to open the door, it seems my level is one level shy of being able to pick up this door opening weapon.

I am not sure I can go back and keep my place. Is there a fix for this? Do I have to start over or something?

Comment: You can pick it up, you just can't use it.

Comment: @Frank - I cannot pick it up. Tried that, unless I am doing something really stupid and missing something.

Comment: is your inventory full?

Comment: @Spartacus - now I feel stupid....That was the issue. I actually had 14 items in a 12 item backpack. Once I dumped some, I could pick up the "trigger" and Claptrap opened a portal. If you post, I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to make sure that your inventory isn't full.

Comment: What really gets me is that I could have had some very powerful weapons that I could have "Grown into" during game play instead of struggling with level 22 and 23 guns. I think I have more hours logged in a respawning record with this game:). Oh, and I lost about one pound of hair that I pulled out in frustration.